# "Too many connections" Java + Msql

Tags: java, mysql

Olá, estou com seguinte problema, eu tenho uma função que busca no banco e retorna um objeto.
Tenho uma função "for" que chama esse metodo quase que 300 vezes, devido a essa quantidade de chamadas o mysql está retornando o seguinte erro.

```
Algo deu errado ao fazer uma ação envolvendo formulações. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"
```

O codigo abaixo. Não faço ideia do que me resta fazer para impedir que esse erro ocorra, já que estou fechando o Statement, Resultset e a conexão em cada consulta. Poderiam me ajudar com isso? Obrigado.

```
 private Formulacao retornaFormulacaoDoItem(Item item) throws Exception {
    Connection cx = br.com.projeto.Conexao.Conexao.abrir();
    try {

        String comando = "SELECT * FROM Formulacao WHERE fk_item = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = cx.prepareStatement(comando);
        ps.setInt(1, item.getIdItem());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Formulacao f = new Formulacao();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        NutrienteDAO nutri = new NutrienteDAO();
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString("operador") != null) {
                list.add(rs.getString("operador"));
            } else if (rs.getString("fk_nutriente") != null) {
                list.add(rs.getString("fk_nutriente"));
            } else {
                list.add(nutri.retornaUmNutriente(rs.getInt("fk_nutriente")).getQuantidade());
            }
        }
        String[] re = new String[list.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            re[j] = list.get(j).toString();
        }
        f.setCalculo(re);
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        return f;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Algo deu errado ao retornar os dados de formula do item" + e);
    } finally {
        cx.close();
    }
}
```

Classe de conexão com banco.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author jpsa
 */
public class Conexao {
    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "123456";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miner";
    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Conectar ao banco
    public static Connection abrir() throws Exception {
        // Registrar o driver
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        // Capturar a conexão
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
        // Retorna a conexao aberta
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione sua classe de conexao também, talvez o problema esteja nela.

Comment: @DiegoF Coloquei.

Comment: Já tentou fexar o `ps` e `rs` no bloco finally ?

Comment: Já verificou se esta função não está sendo chamada paralelamente (multithreads)?

Comment: Você está fazendo uma conexão por consulta? Normalmente você faz a conexão fora do loop, faz o que tem que fazer e fecha depois. Dependendo do caso, dá pra deixar a conexão aberta durante a vida do aplicativo, mas depende da escala em que vai ser usado.

Comment: Olhando esse código não sei dizer com certeza se você está usando pool de conexões. Aparentemente está (de outro modo inclusive os 300 comandos ficariam incrivelmente lentos). A parada é a seguinte: em um pool, a conexão não é fechada imediatamente ao ser abandonada - ela só é fechada depois de um tempo sem uso, de modo que o seu código não fecha a conexão quando você dá um *close*, mas apenas devolve ela para o pool. A próxima solicitação vem muito rápido e acaba abrindo uma nova conexão. Enfim, basicamente você está fazendo errado.

Comment: Você está descobrindo por quê gerenciar a conexão dentro da própria rotina que lê e manipula dados **não é uma boa prática**. Uma boa prática é abrir a conexão no começo da requisição principal, e utilizar a mesma conexão para executar todos os comandos da requisição, em todas as rotinas e subrotinas que atendem a requisição (a não ser que você quisesse algum tipo de paralelismo).

Comment: Na verdade, não se trata de boa prática ou não (não existe nenhuma razão para algo ser chamado de  "boa prática" ou "má prática" em programação, isso é uma lenda furada). No caso, é errado mesmo, e a razão verdadeira é o que o Caffé explicou depois da parte da boa prática :)

Comment: A conexão estava no metodo construtor normal, eu só crirei essa conexão "cx" para ver se fechava a conexão assim, O Loop de que falo  não está no "metodo retornaFormulacaoDoItem()" e sim em outra classe que chama esse metodo no loop .

Comment: Furada é isso que você falou, @Bacco, uma nova lenda, muito mal embasada, ajudando a reduzir a qualidade dos softwares produzidos por profissionais que ainda estão ganhando experiência. Uma pena... Felizmente não tenho visto muito terreno pra essa nova balelinha por aí.

Comment: @Bacco Só pra não ir muito longe, atendo-se apenas a este exemplo específico, não é errado como você falou. É apenas má prática - afinal compila, passa no teste automatizado, e até funciona pra uma quantidade menor de registros, e poderia nunca dar erro. Então não é necessariamente errado, mas é necessariamente uma má prática, que eventualmente pode se revelar (como acabou se revelando). Acreditar na baboseira de que "não existe boa prática" não é uma boa prática :D

Comment: @caffé não é questão de fé, é que na prática, tudo que é chamado de boa prática ou má prática precisa de uma explicação, então o termo é apenas ruído. E como é um termo que em nada acrescenta de informação palpável, acaba sendo usado absurdamente mais por quem não tem como se explicar. Vira uma muleta, e seu uso continuado acaba refletindo um problema maior do usuário. Que o meu termo "errado" não seja o melhor, mas "má prática" também não diz nada. Melhor falar que é "problemático por motivo x, y, z", que é o que você explicou depois, pondo o foco na razão do problema, e não no termo-coringa.

Comment: @Bacco Não, meu caro. Errado. Nem tudo precisa de uma boa e compreensível explicação imediatamente. Muitas vezes nem estamos preparados ainda para entender a explicação a fundo e de coração, então pode ser uma grande perda de tempo. Se você fosse esperar compreender em profundidade todos os passos corretos para produzir um bom software antes de fazê-lo, o teu primeiro bom software ia sair aos 60 anos de carreira. Uma explicação superficial de saída muitas vezes adianta o processo de aprendizado, muitas vezes até explicação nenhuma pode ser útil. É assim que funciona em todos os campos.

Comment: @Caffé fica a cargo dos leitores optar por seguir suas recomendações ou as minhas, acho que é desnecessário eu prolongar a discussão aqui, insisto no meu ponto com uma razão que vai muito além da sua pessoa, aproveite quem quiser. Mas se você acha que do seu jeito é melhor pras pessoas, siga em frente ué. MInha experiência diz que não, mas também diz que não tem sentido ficarmos discutindo (até pq não é você exatamente que eu quero convencer de nada, e acredito que a recíproca seja verdadeira). Assim, me dou por satisfeito com o que eu disse anteriormente.

Comment: Gente, sobre boas praticas vamos deixar isso para as aulas de interface homem maquina, e boas praticas de projeto da faculdade, por enquanto vamos focar em um problema de banco de dados.

Comment: @Bacco E ainda, a minha explicação foi bem superficial, e citei muito superficialmente só um dos muitos problemas que essa má prática pode causar. Você acha suficiente? Acha que fui muito além de dizer que é não é "boa prática"? Pois eu acho que não cheguei nem perto de ser suficiente em minha explicação (tanto é que o AP não entendeu, dá pra ver pelo seu comentário seguinte). Então qualquer explicação superficial serve? Apenas para evitar de usar a expressão "boa prática"? Neste caso, chegamos a um acordo (exceto que eu não tenho nada contra este termo).

Comment: @joaopaulosantosalmeida, deixa a gente bater papo. Estamos com tempo :D

Comment: @joaopaulosantosalmeida Por favor, faça um único *DriverManager.getConnection* e utilize esta mesma conexão para todo o processo, e nos diga se o erro some (e mostre o código, claro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Olhando apenas o método, está correto. Você faz a consulta e fecha os `ResultSet` e `PreparedStatement` em seguida. Eu apenas colocaria os `closed()` no `finally`, junto com a conexão.

Como o pessoal diz nos comentários.. O problema esta em você chamar isso "300" vezes.. pq quando pedimos para fazer um closed nos objetos, esse closed não é imediato. Pode levar alguns milisegundos, e nesse meio termo, você continua bombardeando a base pedindo mais conexões.

A solução seria usar a mesma conexão, então tente diminuir as chamadas ao `getConnection`... fazer algo como manter uma única conexão e usar essa para fazer as 300 chamadas:

```
public static Connection abrir() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    if (conn != null) {
      Class.forName(DRIVER);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Um teste que costumo fazer é monitorar na base as conexões existentes, isso costuma deixar bem claro o que acontece.

É errado deixar assim.. mas apenas para teste, comente o `cx.close()`, mesmo que a conexão fique aberta o tempo todo, você consegue testar e confirmar onde esta o problema.. então tentar deixar fora do for esse passo.